# "Sometimes", "oftentimes" — is there a -times word for "very rarely"?

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests, adverbs, analogy, morphology

If something happens [sometimes](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/sometimes), it happens occasionally.
If something happens [oftentimes](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/oftentimes), it happens often.

Is there an equivalent word for something happening very rarely?

Comment: The word "**betimes**" means "*in good time*" or "*in its own season*", and usually implies "*not any time soon*", which you might be able to stretch to mean "*not frequently*". Outside of that, I'm not personally aware of too many more "-*times*" words.

Comment: Infrequently or just rarely

Comment: 'Seldomtimes' is used, but less often even than 'oftentimes'. I don't understand why your question isn't just 'Is there a synonym for _rarely_?' or 'Is there a synonym for _rarely_ ending in _times_?'

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I'm sorry I didn't phrase the question correctly.

Comment: @DanBron I like "**betimes**". Actually never encountered that word before.

Comment: **Betimes** is an archaism. https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=betimes&year_start=1700&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cbetimes%3B%2Cc0

Comment: You haven't given a context for the question, but be advised that **seldomtimes** is also an archaism. https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=seldomtimes&year_start=1600&year_end=2000&corpus=18&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cseldomtimes%3B%2Cc0

Comment: @TRomano if a word is an archaism, should it not be considered for an accepted answer?

Comment: @TRomano How so? Would a word which is an archaism not be considered proper English? I'm not trying to sound argumentative, I'm genuinely curious.

Comment: @Daft: Hoping to avoid a debate on what is "proper"...  but yes, it would not be "proper" to use archaisms in contexts where contemporary diction is expected.

Comment: @RegDwigнt Changing the title narrowed the question. Why did you do that?

Comment: What's wrong with *often* and *seldom*?

Comment: @ssdecontrol nothing.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Is there a *-times* word for rarely?  Geoffery Chaucer certainly thought so when in *The Clerk’s Tale* he whilom wrote:

> To that I nevere erst thoughte, streyne me.
>       I me rejoysed of my liberte,
>       That **seelde tyme** is founde in mariage.
>       Ther I was free, I moot been in servage.

As you see, old Chaucer wasn’t much of a speller.

We would today write his *seelde time* without spaces, spelling it sometimes *seld-time* or *seldtime* but othertimes written out more in full as *seldom-time* or *seldomtime*. And as ofttimes occurs with such adverbs for reasons too complex to explore in this question, we might also add an *‑s* to  make it *seldtimes* or *seldomtimes* instead.

Alas that *seldtimes* should be so seldom seen today, now that *seldom* is used for *seldomtime*’s purpose!

Historically, such adverbs have appeared under guise of all manner of spelling and punctuation. For example, in *Measure for Measure*  Shakespeare wrote, albeit perhaps for the sake of the verse’s meter and rhyme, that

> This a gentle provost: **Seldom-when**
>    is the steeled gaoler the friend of men.

As with adverbs ending in *‑when*, *‑while* or *‑whiles*, and *‑day* or *‑days*, people would form new adverbs by colliding shorter words with *‑time* or *‑times* anywhen they pleased.  The OED attests such stunning adverbs as:

- aforetime
- aforetimes
- albetimes
- a-nightertime
- a-night-times
- beforetime
- beforetimes
- betime
- betimes
- between-times
- daytimes
- heretoforetime
- night-times
- oftentime
- oftentimes
- oft-time
- oft-times
- one-time
- othertime
- other-times
- quarter time
- seldom-time
- seldom-times
- seld-time
- sometime
- sometimes
- toforetime

Although some of these adverbs were aforetimes written out as separate words, you should still think of them as single adverbs no matter whether they’re spelled with a space or hyphen or written with neither in keeping today’s preferred style of cleanliness.   After all, in speech where they originate you cannot hear a space or a hyphen, so this is merely orthographic convention, not grammar.

Courageous writers might be unbewhile tempted to mint their own coinages of this sort as Chaucer and Shakespeare were themselves fearlessly wont to do.   However, it is probably best that these adverb-making strategies not be thought of as productive combining forms nowadays unless you’re up for some feather ruffling.

In so unbending a world that even such unremarkable adverbs as *daytimes* or *Tuesdays* can freak out the unfamiliar, freely using agèd words like *seldtimes* risks making unfriends of an otherwise amicable audience.

Stick to *seldom* and no one will notice you — presuming, of course, that that is your goal.  If not, then do as you please.

Comment: This is a brilliant answer, much appreciated! Very well written indeed!

Comment: I'll try and work that list of adverbs into my everyday vocabulary. **Torforetime** is fantastic.

Comment: Over the years, I [have betimes been](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22have+betimes+been%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1&gws_rd=ssl) found using "betimes" to mean "from time to time, at rare intervals". Which seems to be the intended sense in most of those linked written instances. I've only just looked the word up and discovered that (according to *OED*) this isn't one of the dictionary-endorsed meanings. It won't make me change future (rare) usage, though.

Comment: +1 for seldom-times. I've actually heard that one before.

Comment: "Seldom times" is not only one I've heard before, but how I immediately "translated" Chaucer. You might want to bold that word for those who will find this and are looking for a quick answer.

Comment: How can one upvote more than once? ;-) Thanks (with a bit of envy, I would love to be able to write like that even in my mothertongue).

Answer (score 1):

The phrase [once in a blue moon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blue_moon) might suit. It describes something that happens very rarely.

Comment: That is not a word that ends in *-times*, which was what the question asked. This attempts to answer some other question, not this one.

Comment: @tchrist The original question did not specifically request that the answer end in *-times*. The title has been edited by an admin.

Comment: @Daft Correct me if I’m wrong, but I believe you requested a word equivalent to *sometimes* and *oftentimes*. I don’t understand how “once in a blue moon” meets that criterion, but your inchage may vary.

Comment: @tchrist No I don't think you are necessarily wrong but I never said it absolutely had to end in *-time*. If that particular word existed that would be great, but I'm happy to entertain any suggestion at all.

Comment: @tchrist *but your inchage may vary*. inchage?

Comment: @Daft: I upvoted tchist's comment specifically because his "inchage" brought a smile to my face. It's just a (witty) variant on [*your **mileage** may vary*](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/your_mileage_may_vary), cunningly implying the issue is somewhat trivial (or something close to that! :) If we were all as quick as him, I've no doubt he'd have written YIMY and expected us to extrapolate the altered word from the standard YMMV.

Comment: I would have assumed you wanted a "-times" word even with the old question. If you're not looking for a "-times" word, you might as well just use "rarely," just like you could use "often" and "occasionally."

Comment: This answer should not be downvoted. **The title was modified after this answer was posted**.

Answer (score -2):

> seldomtimes

I believe this is the word you are after.

Comment: This answer has already been given.